# Meaning of mesh_size

Tags: python, mesh, numerical-methods, triangulation, finite-element-analysis

In the following, does "mesh_size" refer to the maximum perimeter or maximum area of each element?

```
with pygmsh.geo.Geometry() as geom:
    geom.add_polygon(
        [
            [0.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 0.0],
            [1.0, 1.0],
            [0.0, 1.0],
        ],
        mesh_size=0.1,
    )
    mesh = geom.generate_mesh()
```

The PyPI website of pygmsh provides little information.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://pygmsh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common.html#pygmsh.common.point.Point):

[image]

You might wanna checkout [pygmsh repo](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh) for more info. As per the [discussion](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/issues/984) earlier regarding the inclusion of `mesh_size` function into the `pygmsh` library, this is how they defined `mesh_size`:

```
def mesh_size(entity_dim, entity_tag, x, y, z):
    return 1.0e-2 + (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more paranoid question: element size means the area right?

Comment: I am not exactly sure but mesh_size should represent the area. You can follow this [discussion](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/issues/984) that initiated the conversation regarding their plan to include `mesh_size` function in the `pygmsh` library. The author of the library is directly involved in the discussion, so I believe it'd give you better insights.

Comment: I also updated my answer to include the link to this discussion and the function definition.